# Angular AOT Relative paths in components

Tags: angular, relative-path, aot

I'm asking here because I could't find complete documentation online.
The example [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) is too simple.
I've an app with several components and some modules. After compile with ngc, I had lot of errors. The way I found to fix them was use relative paths.
So I use '***moduleId: module.id,***' in all my components.
But now the compiler tells me:
' ***Cannot find name 'module'*** '

As I understand, that is becuase I'm declaring the following compile options for AoT:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
   ---> "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

Instead of using  ***"module": "commonjs",***.
How can I fix this?

How can I use relative paths at the same time I want to generate the AOT build?

thanks!

Comment: If you use webpack, you could check angular2-template-loader. Then in your component metadata just set like that - templateUrl: './yourtemplate.component.html'. There is a lot of troubles with ngc still :(

Comment: It's possible to create one js file with the whole app (minfied) using webpack? That is what I'm looking for .. a process to create one file with the whole app (js, html, css).

Comment: Yes of cours. Take a look here - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick (and maybe dirty) fix is just to write the path directly as a string in the moduleId parameter.

So instead of:

```
moduleId: module.id
```

Write:

```
moduleId: 'path/to/my/app/'
```

This you can use with Component Relative Paths during development, and when creating the AoT bundle ngc won't complain about not finding module.id.